# why msg box is not working when i try to run a loop with VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to run a loop to test if the length of strings in a column have at least ten characters. I debugged and there was no problem. However, I tested it with a string with less than 10 characters, the msg box wouldn't pop up. I am very new to VBA so could anyone please point out what my problem is? Thank you so much.

```vb
Sub MsgBoxforLenLessThanTen()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim length As Integer

    i = 1
    With wsData.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
        Do Until i > lastRow
            length = Len(Range("A1").Offset(0, 1))
            If length < 10 Then MsgBox "not enough characters"
            i = i + 1
            Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you checking the data in column A or B ? Your code checks in B (`Range("A1").Offset(0, 1)`.

Comment: You're always checking the same one cell.

Answer (score 2):

Please see below your corrected code, checking column "A" though. See comments for further details:

```vb
Option Explicit 'always use this, it will enforce you to declare your variables, which is well.. important.

Sub MsgBoxforLenLessThanTen()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lastRow As Long 'Declare your variable
    lastRow = wsData.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'You've declared your variable above for the sheet, use it

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim length As Integer
    Dim msgValue As String: msgValue = "Not enough characters"

    'try the for loop, is much easier
    With wsData
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            length = Len(.Cells(i, "A"))
            If length < 10 Then
                'MsgBox msgValue
                'Debug.Print msgValue & " at: " & .Cells(i, "A").Address
                .Cells(i, "B").Value = msgValue
            Else
                'do something else
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** changed msgbox output to column B instead. I recommend you reading about the [Immediate Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2019) and [Locals Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/locals-window), they help massively in debugging your code, especially when you step through (`F8`).

Comment: Thank you. But after I click ok after msg box pop up, it won't disappear. Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: It won't dissapear or it will keep coming? As per the above, you will get a message for each populated cell in column `A`. I'll change the above code to put the message in column `B` instead of a message box, would that help?